# the calculation conditions IF in dictionaray

Tags: python, dictionary

I don't understand the calculation condition `IF` if dictionary :-

Why when the code

```
dlist = [{'Bilbo':'Ian','Frodo':'Elijah'} , {'Bilbo':'Martin','Thorin':'Richard'}]

k = 'Bilbo'

[ ks[k] if k in ks else 'NOT PRESENT' for ks in dlist]
```

But I when  wrote the code

```
[ ks[k]  for ks in dlist if k in ks else 'NOT PRESENT' ]
```

I get a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: Because, that's the syntax?

Comment: i dont understand why . first should begin the condition For then only condition If . Am i right ?

Comment: +1 for the concept of the question. This isn't about 'working code' - @Mikhail has working code. This is about why Python structures it this way. Perhaps it is a better question for programmers, but still an interesting one.

Answer (score 2):

```
[ks[k] if k in ks else 'NOT PRESENT' for ks in dlist]
```

implies

```
[(ks[k] if k in ks else 'NOT PRESENT') for ks in dlist]
```

Your proposal of

```
[ ks[k]  for ks in dlist if k in ks else 'NOT PRESENT' ]
```

cannot have those parentheses placed implicitly in a sensible way. Here are the various ways of grouping the syntax. None of them do what you likely intended:

```
[(ks[k] for ks in dlist) if k in ks else 'NOT PRESENT']
[ks[k] for ks in (dlist if k in ks else 'NOT PRESENT')]
[ks[k] for ks in dlist if k in ks]
```

Comment: Thanks. your answer is very clear

Answer (score 2):

@Mikhail, I understand the way you are thinking on this one, this is not so much a "my code doesn't work" question as it is a "why does Python do it this way around?". I tripped over it too for a while, what tripped me up is that I was considering it like an assignment statement for example:

```
my_greeting = "Good morning" if is_morning else "Good Evening"
```

This reads completely literally: "Give me "Good Morning" if ..., otherwise give me "Good Evening" and bind this to my_greeting". An assignment statement like this is common to see, and in other C-like languages they even have the turnary operator specifically for this. However, this is not the same in a list comprehension.

A list comprehension (in Python) should be viewed (and read) slightly differently.

```
time_of_day = ["AM", "AM", "PM", "AM"]
def is_morning(x):
    return True if x == "AM" else "False"

my_greetings = ["Good Morning" if is_morning(x) else "Good Evening" for x in time_of_day]
```

Now we need to 'read' this differently, because the logic is slightly different. I always begin from the right hand side (and I know that it should be read left to right, but I like to know what we are dealing with first). So I would read reads:

```
1. from the sequence 'time_of_day', draw x
2. for each x in 'time_of_day' give me "Good Morning", otherwise "Good Evening" (based on the predicate)
```

A simpler description would be:

```
my_even_numbers = [x if not (n % 2) else "Odd" for x in range(1, 100)]
```

Which draws x from range(1, 100), and tests if it is even or not.

Now the really annoying thing is, that I completely agree with you on a logic basis! It would make more sense to me to read: `[x from xs, if (conditions...)]`, and this is how other languages (like Haskell) do things. But not Python. So long story short, the syntax is the syntax, and we have to abide by it :)

---

For comparison, here is a similar example using Haskell, which I think is more inline with the way you have described how you think (expression, followed by conditions):

```
myGreeting x = if x == "AM"
                    then "Good Morning"
                    else "Good Evening"
```

or as a list comprehension which responds to "AM" only:

```
timeOfDay = ["AM", "AM", "PM", "AM"]
goodMorning = [(myGreeting x) | x <- timeOfDay, x == "AM"]
```

Comment: thanks for explanation . for example code is right but i used the same logic                                                           <blink> S = {-4, -2, 1, 2, 5, 0}
zero_sum_list = [ (x,y,z) for x in S for y in S for z in S if sum((x,y,z))==0 ] </blink>

Comment: the main mistake in my code below is comparing values with keys in dictionary. with List my logic is correct

Answer (score 1):

yours code dont works too. As i understand in first line we compare values with key.

```
[(ks[k] for ks in dlist) if k in ks else 'NOT PRESENT']
[ks[k] for ks in (dlist if k in ks else 'NOT PRESENT')]
NameError: name 'ks' is not defined
```